# Cannot access element of 2d heap vector using operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, vector, heap-memory

I have a 2d vector that needs to be allocated on the heap and am using the below line of code to declare and size it.

`vector<vector<double>> *myArray = new vector<vector<double>>(x, vector<double>(y));`

where `x` and `y` are the number of rows and columns respectively.

When I try to access an element of the vector using `myArray[0][0] = 3.0;`, I get the following error,

*error: no viable overloaded '='*

*myArray[0][0] = 3.0;*

I would appreciate any help in figuring this out.

**Notes:**

1. The number of rows and columns needs to be dynamic, hence `myArray` is on the heap.
2. The array needs to be resizable, which is why I am using std::vector.
3. I understand that I can create a vector of vectors (number of rows) and then in a for-loop resize each row element to the required number of columns. What I do not understand is why the above code does not work since as far as I know it should perform the same function.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a pointer? And what is `dataArray`?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

For some <strike>strange</strike> invalid reason, you are using a pointer to a vector. Since `operator[]` works with pointers, when you do

```
myArray[0][0] = 3.0;
```

you are actually accessing a `vector<double>`, not a `double`, because `myArray[0]` gets you a `vector<vector<double>>`.

The obvious fix is not to use a pointer in the first place:

```
vector<vector<double>> myArray(x, vector<double>(y));
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what is going on now.

I am using a pointer since the 2dim vector `myArray` is encapsulated in a class. The constructor accepts the number of rows and columns as arguments and initializes the memory on the heap using `new`.

I was trying to not have to resize each row individually in a loop if the array is declared on the stack.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @muppet Just initialize it like I showed. You really don't need a pointer to a newed object.

Answer (score 2):

must be:

```
(*dataArray)[0][0] = 3.0
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If it fix the problem, why cannot be an answer?
it is not clarification request nor critique.

Comment: OP wanted help figuring out the problem. Your one line does just (maybe) gives working piece of code, it does not really help in figuring out what was wrong originally.